# Event listener isn't working with the custom cell renderer in ag-grid Angular

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I have set-up a simple column definition:

```
{
          headerName: "Probabilité",
          headerToolName: "Consultez les échelles",
          field: "pbt",
          editable: true,
          cellRenderer: params => {
            return `
            <hr>
            <select class="form-control"  (change)="UpdateRisqueBrut($event.target);"
            >
                <br>
                <option>1- Très improbable</option>
                <option>2- Peu probable</option>
                <option>3- Possible</option>
                <option>4- Probable</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
            `;
          }
        }
```

Which renders this way:
[image]
As you may have noticed, I have set-up a listener in the custom cell render called that logs the option chosen among the typescript list.

> UpdateRisqueBrut

Here's the listener definition:

```
 public UpdateRisqueBrut(risque) {
    console.log(risque.value);
  }
```

I am getting no errors but nothing shows-up in the console once the option is chosen.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can also be achieved with AgGrid `'agSelectCellEditor / agPopupSelectCellEditor'`

```
headerName: 'Probabilité',
field: 'make',
editable: true,
cellEditor:'agSelectCellEditor',
cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['1- Très improbable','2- Peu probable','3- Possible','4- Probable']
}
```

On Grid option listen for cell value changed

```
onCellValueChanged: function(event) {
        console.log('onCellValueChanged: Probabilité' + ' = ' + event.newValue);
    },
```

I was also able to achieve your code with below change

```
{headerName: "Probabilité",
     editable: true, 
     cellRenderer: params => {
              return `
              <hr>
              <select onchange="myFunction(this)">
                  <option value='1- Très improbable'>1- Très improbable</option>
                  <option value='2- Peu probable'>2- Peu probable</option>
                  <option value='3- Possible'>3- Possible</option>
                  <option value='4- Probable'>4- Probable</option>
              </select>
              <hr>`;
            }
      }

function myFunction(t)
{
  console.log(t.value);
}
```

The working demo link is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9pkhvAaOvaA5X6dWYLh2?p=preview).

Hope this helps.

Comment: First, since I am working with angular, I have to wrap onchange with () so the listener becomes like this:(onchange)="myFunction(this)". Elsewhere the Angular gives this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined.  (I find this a bit strange if anyone cares to explain you are welcome)

Comment: Second, even after I place the parenthesis and I get no errors, I am back to square one. That is as I said in my post, I get no errors but nothing shows-up on the console :(. (I really don't understand why doesn't this work even though it works on Plunker!). Thanks for your help, anyways!

Comment: And could you please explain why did you use this instead of $event.target in the listener

Comment: Even if I try to console.log('RandomString') this doesn't work. It seems like the listener onchange isn't even firing-up so to speak

Comment: And if I place the same code in the html file, it works! So I think this has something to do with ag-grid. I think I'll post another question in SO to further explain this.

Comment: Here's the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950516/event-listener-works-in-component-html-file-but-doesnt-work-inside-a-cell-in-ag

Comment: Sorry for all of this chaos